# How to pass vector to a row in an array in Excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an array, and a vector. I want to pass/replace a row in the array with the vector.

```
2d array, as below
arr = [[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [a, b]]       <--- replace with vct here

...where vct = [[5, 6]]
```

While it can be done unsophisticatedly using the naive looping, I wonder if there is any creative workaround for it. Example as below.

Using naive looping:

```
For i = 1 to 2
    arr(3, i) = vct(i)
Next i
```

...or some clever workaround:

```
arr(3, :) = vct    ...where ":" represents "all columns"
```

Result expected:

```
arr = [[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]]
```

Tbh I have low expectation for vba since even the simple array indexing isn't actually a thing. I just hope if anybody wanna take a stab on this to provide a solution. Tq

---

Edit to improve question clarity by adding vba code block. See below

```vb
    Dim arr(1 to 3, 1 to 2) as Integer
    Dim vct(1 to 2) as Integer
    Dim i as Integer

    ' filling in arr
    arr(1, 1) = 1
    arr(1, 2) = 2
    arr(2, 1) = 3
    arr(2, 2) = 4
    arr(3, 1) = 10
    arr(3, 2) = 20

    ' filling in vct
    vct(1) = 5
    vct(2) = 6

    ' passing the vector vct into last row of arr using for loop
    For i = 1 to 2
        arr(3, i) = vct(i)
    Next i

    ' as a result,
    ' arr(3, 1) = 5, and
    ' arr(3, 2) = 6
    ' which does its work perfectly
    ' but I am looking if there is any possibility
    ' to have a non-looping approach such as below
    ' arr(3, :) = vct
    '  
    ' this is because I am too accustomed to python syntax
    ' where it can be done as using ":"
```

Comment: are you shure that you using VBA?

Comment: I am using vba. I assume you are asking due to the syntax that I used in my code block example. They are not in vba syntax, rather just to represent my points. Do you think I should modify them to be exactly in vba syntax to avoid confusion?

Comment: i think you must post a piece of code so we can understand that you want to do, also you can read this first https://bettersolutions.com/vba/arrays/index.htm

Comment: Noted. Let me edit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sound like you want something like this

```
  Sub test()
  Dim vaTest As Variant

    vaTest = Array(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(4, 5, 6))
        Debug.Print vaTest(0)(1) ' Prints 2
    vaTest(0) = Array(7, 8, 9) ' changing first array
        Debug.Print vaTest(0)(1) ' Prints 8
  End Sub
```

Comment: is `vaTest` a 2d array, or 1d array of 1d array elements? My requirement is that accessing the `vaTest` should be like `vaTest(0, 1)` instead of `vaTest(0)(1)`

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin Actually he *must not* accept the first answer. While it is a good practice to accept the first correct answer (if there are 2 equal answers) he is free to decide which answer fits better to his question and choose the one which gave the best explanation to the question. This makes people answering not only correct answers but also good anwser with good explanations. • So it is a common practice to accept the answer that you think fits best (even if it came later) and upvote for the other ones that are correct too. This decision is completely up to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use array counting 0 based because you can easily use `Array(1, 2)` to create a vector.

```
Sub test()     
    Dim Vectors() As Variant

    'fill it with 3 vectors (0 to 2)
    Vectors = Array(Array(1, 2), Array(3, 4), Array("a", "b"))

    'replace third vector with another one
    Vectors(2) = Array(5, 6)
End Sub
```

**Before**
[image]

**After**
[image]

To directly access one of these vectors use:

```
Debug.Print Vectors(2)(0) '=5
Debug.Print Vectors(2)(1) '=6
```

Or to extract eg the second vector use

```
Dim SecondVector() As Variant
SecondVector = Vectors(1)

Debug.Print SecondVector(0) '=3
```

For further information about using arrays I recommend reading:
[The Complete Guide to Using Arrays in Excel VBA](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-array/)

Comment: It works, thanks. Ps/ note that @dmitrij also giving the same answer. Credit to both of you. Upvote this answer for the diagram aid.